# Validar formulario en caso de error no enviar

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

actualmente tengo el siguiente formulario

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'prueba','name'=>'form', 'id'=>'form','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off', 'onsubmit' => 
     'agregar(this); return false;'))!!}

  <button type="submit" id="add" name="add">Guardar</button>

$('#add').on("click",function(){
    event.preventDefault();
        var error= true;
       var msg = "";
       
  if (precio==""){   
     msg +="\nDebe ingresar Precio.";
     error= false;
  }  

  if(error== false){
    alert(msg);
    return error;
    }
    form.submit()
```

Cuando presiono el botón guardar, evalúa la funciona si esta correcta emite un mensaje en blanco (no debería aparecer, y si hay un error emite un mensaje pero igual lo envía, cómo podría hacer para que se parara si consigue un error?, y si no consigue error envie sin emitir el alert en blanco?, gracias por la ayuda que pudieran brindarme

Comment: Puedes agregar un `event.preventDefault()` al inicio de la función, y un `form.submit()` al final

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @porloscerrosΨ me fue de diez, muchas gracias

Comment: Genial, puedes agregar una respuesta con cómo lo resolviste así queda y le puede servir a otros usuarios con el mismo problema

Comment: Listo @porloscerrosΨ ahi lo edite para colocarlo como quedó finalmente con tu ayuda, gracias por todo saludos